# Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.(MULTILINGUAL)

Tags: c#, asp.net, resources, multilingual, facebook-c#-sdk

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["Lang"] == null) { 
                Session["Lang"] = Request.UserLanguages[0];
            }                
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                LoadString();    
            }    
        }

protected void ddLang_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["Lang"] = ddLang.SelectedValue;
            LoadString();
        }

private void LoadString(){
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(Session["Lang"].ToString());
            rm = new ResourceManager("ASPMultilingual.App_GlobalResources.Lang", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            ci = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
            btnLogIn.Text = rm.GetString("Login", ci);
        }
```

Here is my code and the resource file I store at **App_GlocalResources** as `Lang.ch-CH.resx, Lang.en.EN.resx and Lang.de.DE.resx`.

After I compile, it throws an error and points to `btnLogIn.Text = rm.GetString("Login", ci);`.

Inside my resource has the name of Login.

Comment: Have you tried to debug and check ,wheather the lang file is getting loaded properly

Comment: please check whether the Session actually contains the Lang that is required

Comment: i debug already and its point to  btnLogIn.Text = rm.GetString("Login", ci); and say Missing ManifesResourceException was unhandled b user code.

Comment: try 'en-US'....Check [here](http://www.codedigest.com/CodeDigest/207-Get-All-Language-Country-Code-List-for-all-Culture-in-C---ASP-Net.aspx) for different codes

Comment: I dont think it is the matter, its throw me back the error I posted... Herm... any idea?

Comment: I am using asp.net visual studio web express 2013

Comment: is it possible that my code dont have namespace???? (I tried to add namespace but its throw me another error and my lbl,txt all will became red line.

Comment: Using System.Globalization and System.Threading should be present already without which you would have got an error in the first place

Comment: both of them I already using already..

Comment: @Handsome It is not finding the resource Login ? Is it a file or something else can u post this also.

Comment: @MairajAhmad what do you mean?I am having two file name Lang.zh-TW.resx, Lang.en.US.resx. I wish them to be call out but it show me couldnt find file location.. I dont know what I have do wrongly.

Comment: the login is inside the file .resx.

Comment: Can u check in debug mode what is value of rm ?

Comment: do u  mind guide me how can I check it? after I run debug then where can I see?

Comment: its throw me this from debug  "An exception of type 'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "MultiLingual.App_GlobalResources.Lang.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "App_Web_wuhdpyfd" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed."

Answer (score 0):

```cs
rm = new ResourceManager("**ASPMultilingual**.App_GlobalResources.Lang", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

In this line change `ASPMultilingual` namespace to your namespace.