# asp.net inheritance and classes confusion

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

> Compiler Error Message: ASPNET: Make sure that the class defined in
>   this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends
>   the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl).

Here is the code it points to:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

//application namespace
namespace MillerDylanTwoColumn
{

    class _MyClass
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var lbl = sender as Label;
            lbl.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you, let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: The `_MyClass` must inherit from either `Page` or `UserControl`, e.g. `public partial class _MyClass : System.Web.UI.Page` (or `System.Web.UI.UserControl`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASPNET: Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29958733/aspnet-make-sure-that-the-class-defined-in-this-code-file-matches-the-inherits)

Comment: Just detail but I'd try to avoid underscores in class names. Check the class naming guidelines here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/4xhs4564(v=vs.71)
Especially the "Do not use the underscore character (_)".
Although the C# language spec, section 2.4.2 sais:
Identifiers containing two consecutive underscore characters (U+005F) are reserved for use by the implementation. For example, an implementation might provide extended keywords that begin with two underscores.
So you wont have any problems using it but I guess its not best practice...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29958859/4977870)

You need to add namespace before class name in Aspx page in inherits attribute.

```
<%@ Page Title="Some Title" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="ASPMultilingual._Default" %>
```